# Slash commands only available in 1 guild ID

Tags: discord.js, command, slash

I've recently followed a slash command tutorial from discordjs guide. It all works, but the issue is that I am unable to have the slash commands in more than 1 server, as I have manually put the guild ID in, and cannot find a way to get the guild ID when the bot is ready. Here's the code:

```js
const clientID = '942177936553959464';
const guildID = '936781831037157426';

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientID, guildID), // Error is at guildID, as it is not getting the actual guilds ID, just the one I set for testing.
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you register is a guild-specific way of registering slash commands. There are 2 routes you can take.
First - Have an array of guild IDs and loop over them and register it per guild. Something like this would work fine

```js
const clientID = "942177936553959464";
const guilds = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];
guilds.forEach((guildID) => {
    // Register the slash commands here
});
```

Second - Register the slash commands globally(For all guilds).  Do note global commands take some time to be cached and made available by the discord API.

https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#global-commands

Note - The First approach should be followed while the bot is in the development stage and not in production

Comment: You can use the first approach in production for guild-specific commands (when the command shouldn't be global but only used on that specific guild). It's also true that you should definitely use the first approach in development as well, and don't set global commands during development (too slow to iterate due to caching taking up to an hour to update).